# What is the name for the guitar that doesn't have strings?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

I had seen an electric guitar somewhere (can't remember) that resemble one used in guitar hero, but it's a real guitar for playing. It has buttons filling up the frets on each note to replace strings. You can strum without a pick and somehow the "button-guitar" sense the strumming.

I searched on google but couldn't find it (may be I didn't get the name right). What is it called? Electric-button-guitar? Who manufactures it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original and longest-running instrument of the type you describe is the

### [Starr Labs Ztar](http://www.starrlabs.com/)

family of instruments. They've been offering these guitars for more than 25 years.

Also, [Yamaha](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical-instruments/entertainment/lighted_key_fret_instruments/ez_series/ez-ag/?mode=model#tab=product_lineup), the largest music instrument company in the world, has offered a similar guitar, the [EZ-AG](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical-instruments/entertainment/lighted_key_fret_instruments/ez_series/ez-ag/?mode=model#tab=product_lineup), for many years also.

Answer (score 4):

Is it the [HyperTouch](http://www.yankodesign.com/2011/03/25/no-strings-attached/)?

Answer (score 4):

The only two I know of, if we exclude the Guitar Hero/Rock Band ones are:

- The [Miso Kitara](http://www.misadigital.com/index.php?target=kitara&lang=en)
- the [HyperTouch](http://www.coolest-gadgets.com/20110328/hyper-touch-guitar-strings/)

I don't know if the Hypertouch is real yet or still a concept, but the Kitara is available now.

Comment: guess it's the miso I saw. so the name is "Digital Guitar"!

Comment: [Yamaha has had this out for a while as well](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical-instruments/entertainment/lighted_key_fret_instruments/ez_series/ez-ag/?mode=model).